# How do I add constraints programmatically to my UILabel

Tags: swift

Is there a way in swift to have a label and make constraints for it programmatically. For example on all devices to 'Pin to the top' or 'Pin to the right side' so that on all devices it just pins to whatever device is being used.

It's because I've created a label programmatically, so I want to make constraints for it.

If you need more info, just let me know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
        let label = UILabel()
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

This will bind the item to all the edges, making it as big as the screen. Anchor is used to refer to an point in game. which is either its superview or some view on the same level as your current view. You can use references as i did `self.view.trailingAnchor`, and you can also add offsets and insets `view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true`. Or you can name the direct size of something `label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat).isActive = true`. Good luck

Answer (score 5):

You can easily add Constraints programatically using NSLayoutConstraints. Below is the code sample for it. I have used centering constraint , you can use leading and top constraints with height and width.

```
func addLabel(){
    let newView =UILabel()

        self.view.addSubview(newView)

        newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
    }
```

Comment: So this will pin it to all edges of the device?

Answer (score 5):

the code below, will stick your label to top-right as you want, on all d devices,

```
let aLabel = UILabel()

 self.view.addSubview(aLabel)
 aLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
 aLabel.text = " i am a label"
 aLabel.textAlignment = .center
 aLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

 let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: aLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
 let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: aLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])

 self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```