# Swift. An oversized caption in timerLabel

Tags: swift, font-size, countdowntimer

I created a countdown timer by DataComponentsFormatter.
It works fine in certain languages. However, when I use it in English, the caption that appears after I tap "start button", are oversized like the photo below. Although I applied "adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth" to the label, it fixes only the size of the label before the start button is tapped.

If there is any function that I should use to make it a right size, would you advise me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFrkP.png)

This is the timer I use for the label by the way.

func displayUpdate() -> Double {

```
    let setting = 300
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .brief
    formatter.includesTimeRemainingPhrase = true
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]

    let remainCount = settings - count
    let outputString = formatter.string(from: remainCount)
    countDownLabel.text = outputString

     return (remainCount)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your label has width constraints set so the label does not expand beyond the edge of the screen, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48061315/10605227) has an example or you can use the interface builder.
2. Make sure the label's [`minimumScaleFactor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620544-minimumscalefactor) property is set.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908334/uilabel-is-not-auto-shrinking-text-to-fit-label-size) has more details on auto shrinking label text.